# Customizing title page - placing extra text

Tags: vertical-alignment, titles

I am currently working on my title page and trying to set my adress to the bottom left of my page, as far as possible. Unfortanetly, I have no idea how to do it. That's how my code looks like:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy} %eigener Seitenstil
\fancyhf{} %alle Kopf- und Fußzeilenfelder bereinigen
\fancyhead[R]{Titel} %Kopfzeile links
\fancyhead[C]{} %zentrierte Kopfzeile
\fancyhead[L]{Name} %Kopfzeile rechts
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} %obere Trennlinie
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage} %Seitennummer
% \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt} %untere Trennlinie

\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, right=4cm, left=3cm, headheight=15pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[main=ngerman,UKenglish,USenglish,french,russian,bulgarian]{babel}
\usepackage[babel,style=swiss]{csquotes}


\pagenumbering{arabic}

\author{X Man}
\title{\centering {\enquote{Where is the work?} -- Eine Spurensuche}}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
    \newgeometry{left=3cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm}
    \begin{footnotesize}
        \raggedright \singlespacing
            X University\\
            X Faculty\\
            X Institute\\
            Seminar X\\
            Sommersemester X\\
            \today \\
%               \vspace{4cm}
        \end{footnotesize}

        \begin{center}

            \centering
            \vspace*{4cm}

            \Huge
        \textbf{Thesis Title}           
    \end{center}
    \begin{raggedright}
        \vspace{200cm}
        \singlespacing \normalfont
        X Man\\
        20 X Street\\
        X\\
        X Town\\
    \end{raggedright}
\end{titlepage}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just replace the extravagant `\vspace{200cm}` with `\vfill`:

[image]